# How to pass GLib.Thread arguments

Tags: vala

Typical GLib.Thread examples i found are a type of:

`new Thread<void*>(null,() => { return null; };`

This works well when not passing arguments to the thread.

The GLib.Thread docs show an example using a class instance to provide thread data.

```
// Start a thread:
MyThread my_thread = new MyThread (10);
Thread<int> thread = new Thread<int>.try ("My fst. thread", my_thread.run);
```

Is this the only way to pass arguments to threads? The docs also say:

> The new thread starts by invoking func with the argument data. Data:
>   an argument to supply to the new thread.

Where is the argument data specified and how is it accessed within the thread?

For example, imagine this callback signature:

```
private string cbThreadSample(int id,string msg, Socket client_socket){
   //...do stuff
   return "good job";
   }
```

my thought for usage was something like:

```
new GLib.Thread<string>("my thread sample",this.cbThreadSample,id,msg, client_socket);
```

Obviously this does not compile. What is the correct way of creating a thread with this callback signature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data argument is part of the delegate you have passed into the thread.

If you do:

```
new GLib.Thread<string>("my thread sample",
  () => this.cbThreadSample(id,msg, client_socket));
```

In the underlying C code, this will be translated to something like this:

```
struct lambda0__data {
  WhateverClass *self;
  int id;
  gchar *msg;
  GSocket client_socket;
};

void *lambda0__func(lambda0__data *context) {
   whatever_class_cbThreadSample(context->self,
     context->id, context->msg,
     context->client_socket));
    return NULL;
}

...
lambda0__data *thread_data = g_new0(lambda0__data);
thread_data->self = self;
thread_data->id = id;
thread_data->msg = gstrdup(msg);
thread_data->client_socket = g_object_ref(socket);
g_thread_try_new("my thread sample", lambda0__func, thread_data);
```

The data parameter passed is associated with the delegate (lambda or method reference). In the case of using a subclass `MyThread`, the instance of `MyThread` will be passed as the data parameter.

This isn't directly accessible. It's passed implicitly as either the captures of a lambda or `this` of an instance.

Also, if you're actually using this for a request handler, you probably want to use a [ThreadPool](https://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.ThreadPool.html).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!